# How can I generate a sub_transaction_number based on a selected main_transaction_number in Django using HTML Form fields?

Tags: python, django, ajax

I want to generate sub_transaction_number base on a selected main_transaction_number from html Forms fields.

The format should
OD2305230101

Where OD is the abbreviation for shipment period store in database. (Retrieved main_transaction_number from sales table, base on the shipment period for the selected main_transaction_number look for it corresponding abbreviation from the shipment period table)

Where 23 is the last two digits of production year also stored in the sales table per main_transaction_number.

Where 052301 is the main_transaction_number select from the form drop down field stored in the sales table

Where 01 is count or number sequence for the selected main_transaction_number

Note:
Multiple of sub_transaction_number can generated for one main_transaction_number which have to follow number sequence with reference to the last sub_transaction_number saved in the sub_transaction_number table.

The main_transaction_number is used as foreign key in a  model called MainTransactionNumber

Eg
main_transaction_numb 052301 can have  sub_transaction_number

OD2305230101
OD2305230102
OD2305230103

The generated sub_transaction_number should be displayed live as value and read only in html form once main_transaction_number is selected from a drop list in the same form

Be able to generate a sub transaction number live once a main transaction number is selected from a drop down list before the form is submitted